# Deriving a percentage in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to derive a percentage change in jquery. I have a ticker which is pulling out 2 values one being the the value and one the value of change. I would like to be able to derive the percentage of this and display this value instead.

I am struggling to do this and i was wondering if there is a easier way to do this.

A current example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/hykdeyoz/

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
            $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" + gstock[i] + "&callback=?", function (response) {
                var stockInfo1 = response[0];
                var divContainer = $('*[data-symbol="' + stockInfo1.t + '"]');

                var stockString1 = '<div class="stockWrapper">' + divContainer.data('title') + ':';
                var stockName1 = stockInfo1.t;
                var stockChange = "";
```

The value I would like to change into a percentage are in red and green (green on indicates level raised or dropped)

Question:

"do you want that if "200" is in red & "10" is in green then it would show as "200" in red & "5%" in green? –  Sac 8 mins ago"

yes, although the 200 can ideally be hidden. and just the percentage shown. another perk would be if the percentage is positive it should be in green and if it is a negative percentage then it should be red. I have used your question to edit the main post. Thanks –  Sam Wilson 1 min ago    edit

Thanks.

Comment: do you want that if "200" is in red & "10" is in green then it would show as "200" in red & "5%" in green?

Comment: yes, although the 200 can ideally be hidden. and just the percentage shown.

another perk would be if the percentage is positive it should be in green and if it is a negative percentage then it should be red. I have used your question to edit the main post. Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hykdeyoz/09/ thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I have updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hykdeyoz/10/) as per your need. Check it out.

```
var percentStock = ((parseFloat(stockInfo1.c)/parseFloat(stockInfo1.l)) * 100);
percentStock = Number((percentStock).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: You're using external data. You should check it's valid, otherwise you could end up with things like `VOLVO VLV NaN%`

Comment: Thankyou, I have encountered one issue though which might be related to the  hird party data but it might also be possible to change. I believe that on larger numbers jump to using a comma, eg 1,200 and then when the percentage is derived using a smaller number eg 0.33 larger percentages are finally quoted as the comma and fullstop dont work well together?  These results appear as abnormally large percentages.

Comment: Yes I have handled that conditions now.

Comment: Thankyou, could i see the latest jsfiddle for this if possible?

Thankyou

Comment: Yes I have edited the answer with the latest fiddle link. Let me know if something goes unhandled as the dataset is live.

Comment: Ah, another question. the styling and the alternative row css is not working with the percentages. the grey background of the percentage cell does not always match the row color.

Is there a easy way to fix this. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hykdeyoz/8/)

```
var percentage = (parseFloat(stockInfo1.c) * 100 / parseFloat(stockInfo1.l)).toFixed(2);
```

I have added logic for showing green & red is here:

```
if(parseFloat(stockInfo1.c) > 0)
    stockChange += '<span class="stockChange "> ';
else
    stockChange += '<span class="stockPrice "> ';
```

For ignoring NaN :

```
var percentage = (parseFloat(stockInfo1.c) * 100 / parseFloat(stockInfo1.l)).toFixed(2);
if(isNaN(percentage)) 
    percentage = 0;
```

And finally add the percentage..

```
stockChange += percentage + '% </span>';
```

In this way you will not get that issue of *'background color change'*..

Comment: he styling and the alternative row css is not working with the percentages. the grey background of the percentage cell does not always match the row color. Is there a easy way to fix this. thanks again

Comment: I can't get what you want to ask.  The grey background of the percentage cell is same as the row's background color. See my Fiddle..

Comment: If you look at https://jsfiddle.net/hykdeyoz/10/ and https://jsfiddle.net/hykdeyoz/8/. In version 10 the percentages have been resolved but the percentage column has now changed colour (the colour is subtle so it might not be apparently obvious) In version 10 a list of 'dead' stocks without any percentages also appear at the bottom of the list unlike the earlier versions.

Comment: I think i have fixed this, sorry I got confused at one of the stages.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to show the percentage changes compared to the previous value, so you need to calculate the old value, by reversing the change, and the showing the percentage compared to that.

```
var newValue = parseFloat(stockInfo1.l.replace(/,/g, ""));
var change = parseFloat(stockInfo1.c.replace(/,/g, ""));
var oldValue = newValue - change;
var percentChange = (change / oldValue * 100).toFixed(2);

stockString1 += '<span class="stockSymbol "> ' + stockInfo1.t + ' </span>';
stockChange += '<span class="stockPrice "> ' + stockInfo1.l + '</span>';
stockChange += '<span class="stockChange "> ' + percentChange + '%</span>';
```

As @blgt pointed out, there is no validation of data, nor there is a different colouring when the change is positive or negative.